# Drawing NGons with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Is OpenGL, given a series of points, able to fill in a polygon or is this only possible by creating lots of trianges?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL)` should give you a filled polygon, as long as the vertices satisfy appropriate conditions (all the points have to be coplanar, and define a convex polygon, iirc).

You'd draw the polygon with the standard `glBegin(GL_POLYGON)`, `glVertex*(coords)` and then `glEnd()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the Ngons planar and convex, OpenGL handles them well.  You'll have to triangulate the polygon yourself if it becomes concave (generally) or the polygon becomes non-planar and you want some algorithm for keeping it as non-generate as possible.